# Multiple delete in visual block mode

Tags: vim, vi

I want to remove the first 4 characters in each line in this block of text:

```
>>> from tslearn.utils import to_time_series
>>> my_first_time_series = [1, 3, 4, 2]
>>> formatted_time_series = to_time_series(my_first_time_series)
>>> print(formatted_time_series.shape)
```

I do `Ctrl-v` `3j` `4x` and only the first character disappears on each line.

```
>> from tslearn.utils import to_time_series
>> my_first_time_series = [1, 3, 4, 2]
>> formatted_time_series = to_time_series(my_first_time_series)
>> print(formatted_time_series.shape)
```

How do I do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Select visually and then delete, so:

`Ctrl-v` `3j` `3l` `x`